# Change Jquery Slider Value as per user Input

Tags: jquery, input, tags

I am trying to change Slider value as per user input but I am not able to figure out the right way being a newbie in Jquery. I understand Javascript but this seems bit different for me.

Here is the code for my input tag :

```
Enter Your Score :<input type="number" id="xcm" />
```

and the Slider I am using is http://codepen.io/jessecfisher/full/symul

Comment: Here's a hacky solution. Use jQuery `.val` to change the text value of the input. And then you will notice that the elements identified by the classes `.ui-slider-range` and `.ui-slider-handle` under the `#vertical-slider` div are responsible for the knob position.

Comment: And then change the `bottom` property to the percentage you want it to be and you should be good.

Comment: The jquery-ui slider API exposes a method for exactly the purpose of setting the value. Use that; no hacky solution required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a jquery-ui slider. The [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#method-value) shows how to do this: the value method on the slider object.

> **value**( *value* ) Set the value of the slider.
>
> *Code examples*: $( ".selector" ).slider( "value", 55 );

I've modified the codepen you posted with this javascript to give you the desired functionality:

```
$( "input#amount").change(function() {
    $( "#slider-vertical" ).slider( "value", $(this).val() );
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yawgs

In order for this to work with your HTML, you'll need to

- update `input#amount` to be your input element (`input#xcm`)
- update `#slider-vertical` to be your slider element (not specified)

Comment: Your code works. I am very much thankful. However, I wanted to clarify one more thing. I am actually also trying to change the color of slider as per user input. When user drags the slider he can see the change but on user input he can't. It shows default color unless slider is touched by user.

Comment: I'd need to see a live example of what you mean, or at least some code with the color change logic.

Comment: hope the below code will show you how I am changing color:
 
   $("#slider-vertical").slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 110,
        value: 0,  
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("input").val("$" + ui.value);
               
            if(ui.value<=110 & ui.value>=100){var r = parseInt(255);
    var y = parseInt(0);
    $("#rest").val("Potentially Toxic!"); }}
            $(".ui-widget-header").css("background-color", "rgb("+r+","+y+",0)");  }});});

Comment: please provide a codepen link of your code, rather than trying to put it into a comment.